# Authenticate against the API, include your API key in the 'Authorization' header, prefixed with 'Key ', in every request

Tags: python, api, authentication, swagger, api-key

As a seller on a marketplace, I would like to access and automate changes (in prices, quantity...etc) to my product offers against competitors on those offers through the marketplace's API("https://seller-api.takealot.com/api-docs/swagger.json") in python. How can I go about doing this? I am supposed to include my API key in an Authorization header to each request in order to be correctly authorised against the API. But I am stuck here, anyone to help please? I am very new to APIs.

The documentation says:

To authenticate against the API, include your API key in the 'Authorization' header, prefixed with 'Key ', in every request.

Example: 'Authorization: Key yourapikey'

Below is my code:

```
import requests
import secrets
import csv

url1 = 'https://seller.takealot.com/api/seller-api/offers'
url2 = 'https://seller.takealot.com/api/seller-api'
headers = {
'Authorization': secrets.API_KEY
}

r = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)
myJson = r.json()
print(myJson)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Netchoice\PycharmProjects\pythonProject21\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Netchoice\PycharmProjects\pythonProject21\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    myJson = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\Netchoice\PycharmProjects\pythonProject21\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 917, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Seller Portal</title>
<base href="/" />

<script>
      (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){         
        h.hj=h.hj||function(){
          (h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)
        };
        h._hjSettings={hjid:2533456,hjsv:6};
        a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
        r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
        a.appendChild(r);
      })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
    </script>

<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-N55WJV4');
    </script>

<script>
    window.onerror = function(error) {
      if (/syntax ?error/i.test(error)) {
        document.querySelector('.global-error').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('#app').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-modern-calendar-datepicker@3.1.6/lib/DatePicker.css" />
<style>
    .global-error {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 20vh auto;
      text-align: center;
      color: silver;
      display: none;
    }

    .global-error > button {
      font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      padding: 0.78571429em 2.5em 0.78571429em;
      border-radius: 0.28571429rem;
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: #DB2828;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Takealot Seller Portal" />
<meta name="description" content="Takealot Seller Portal" />
<meta name="subject" content="ecommerce" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Takealot Online (RF) (Pty) Ltd" />
<meta name="language" content="EN" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<meta name="summary" content="Takealot Seller Portal for Marketplace Sellers" />
<meta name="author" content="Takelaot holdings" />
<meta name="reply-to" content="mp-dev@takealot.com" />
<meta name="owner" content="Takealot Holdings" />
<meta name="url" content="http://seller.takealot.com" />
<meta name="identifier-URL" content="http://seller.takealot.com" />
<meta name="pagename" content="Seller Portal" />
<meta name="category" content="ecommerce" />
<meta name="coverage" content="Worldwide" />
<meta name="distribution" content="Global" />
<meta name="rating" content="General" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
<meta name="target" content="all" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off" />
<meta itemprop="name" content="Takealot Seller Portal" />
<meta itemprop="short_name" content="Takealot" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="Takealot Seller's Portal for resellers in marketplace" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="sellers-platform-ui">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#fff">
<meta name="application-name" content="sellers-platform-ui">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-750x1294.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-1182x2208.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-1242x2148.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png">
<link href="main.css?v=7de3627337e960bb10de5aee0d428219" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<div class="global-error">
<img alt="error image" src="https://www.takealot.com/static/images/react-error.png" />
<br />
<button onclick="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Click to refresh page</button>
</div>

<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-N55WJV4"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
  </noscript>

<div id="app"></div>
<noscript>Javascript is required, please enable and refresh page</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" src="seller.f1604e4f8c138e7972dc.js"></script></body>
<footer>
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script>
      (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
          'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
          event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j = d.createElement(s),
          dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-PF9XJL')
    </script>
<noscript>
      <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PF9XJL" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
<script>
      window._wfx_settings = {
        "ent_id": "86b5bfb0-3c26-11e5-b8d9-448a5b5dd5b8"
      };
    </script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.whatfix.com/prod/86b5bfb0-3c26-11e5-b8d9-448a5b5dd5b8/embed/embed.nocache.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
: 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you have code you can show? That would help us understand what exactly you're having problems with and help with that specifically. Without any code, it seems like you need an open-ended tutorial and we can't tell where to start.

Comment: @Blckknght I have updated my question with my starting code.

Comment: Does the key you're importing from your `secrets` module have a `"Key "` prefix? Because that's the only thing I see likely to be wrong. Maybe if you load that HTML error message in a browser, it will tell you something more, but other than that, I have no idea.

Comment: It doesn't.

API_KEY = "myApiKey"

Answer (score 1):

The API docs you quote suggest that the API key you're sending in your header should have a prefix of `Key`  before the actual key itself. Try:

```
headers = {
'Authorization': f'Key {secrets.API_KEY}'
}
```